# FastAPI: 422 Unprocessable Entity with Image upload while same code is working perfectly for 3.7 but giving error in 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi, uvicorn

**Error is duce to the version. `python 3.7` is working fine and `3.9` is not**

Here is my code:

```
from io import BytesIO
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import Response
import traceback
from rembg.rembg import remove as remove_bg

app = FastAPI(title='BG Remove')

@app.post('/segment')
async def segment_image(image: UploadFile):
    """
    Remove Background from an image
    """
    try:
        print('hello')
        image = await image.read()
        buffer = BytesIO(image)

    except Exception as e:
        e = traceback.format_exc()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=420, detail=f"Image loading error :: {e}")

    try:
        data = remove_bg(buffer)

        return Response(content=data, media_type="image/png")


    except Exception as e:
        e = traceback.format_exc()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=420, detail=f"Segmentation Error:: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("fast_app:app", reload=True, debug = True, host = '0.0.0.0')
```

Every time I send my image in `Postman`, it gives the error as:
[image]

**Butt the main part is that when I run the same code on `python 3.9` it runs so smoothly**

Comment: The fastapi version installed is the same?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: did you run code in console/terminal to see full error message? Maybe it needs to install some module.

Answer (score 1):

```
from fastapi import File, UploadFile, FastAPI
```

try to use it  `UploadFile = File(...)`